# How to execute a batch file whose name is in a variable?

Tags: python, variables

NOTE: I edited this post because people kept thinking I needed today's date in python *when I don't need today's date! I already have the code for today's date!*

**The Problem**

I have a variable for each day of the week, the variable contains a batch file I want to execute.

I have most of the code, I just don't know how to have the variable change based on today's weekday. I even have the code to make the weekday appear, but I don't know how to use that to execute the batch file based on today's day.

Here is the code:

```
import datetime
import subprocess

# obtaining today's date
now = datetime.datetime.now()
tdate = (now.strftime("%A"))
print(tdate)

#the variables for each day:

Monday = """\\VGMSTATION\\Users\\VGMPC2\\Documents\\Vlcscheduler\\Playlist\\Platformer\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat"""
Tueday = """\\VGMSTATION\\Users\\VGMPC2\\Documents\\Vlcscheduler\\Playlist\\shooters beatemup survival\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat """
Wednesday = """\\VGMSTATION\Users\VGMPC2\Documents\Vlcscheduler\Playlist\Action Adventure\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat """
Thursday = """\\VGMSTATION\Users\VGMPC2\Documents\Vlcscheduler\Playlist\sports racing puzzlecard artgames\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat """
Friday = """\\VGMSTATION\Users\VGMPC2\Documents\Vlcscheduler\Playlist\Fighters\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat"""
Saturday = """\\VGMSTATION\Users\VGMPC2\Documents\Vlcscheduler\Playlist\Sega Generation\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat"""
Sunday = """\\VGMSTATION\Users\VGMPC2\Documents\Vlcscheduler\Playlist\Nintendo Generation\\vlcscheduler playlist.bat"""


# What do I put in subprocess.call() so I can run today's batch file?
```

What I have tried:
Someone (thank you for the suggestion@Orhan Solak) gave the suggestion of trying:

```
Monday = "Path\\of\\folder"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
tdate = (now.strftime("%A"))
vars()[tdate]
```

but when I tried that I got:

```
KeyError: "Monday"
```

Probably because none of my variables are dictionaries.

Comment: You getting the `KeyError` because [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) returns a dictionary and the `vars()[tdate]` is trying to look-up the value of `tdate` in it. What is the name of the batch file you want to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your variable with vars()

```
Monday = "Path\\of\\folder"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
tdate = (now.strftime("%A"))
vars()[tdate]
```

output:

```
>>>'Path\\of\\folder'
```

So, as an answer:

```
subprocess.call(vars()[tdate])
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting an key error: 'Monday'. I think its because none of my variables are dictionaries. 

I am going to make a new question because you were the only person who seems to have read my question. Everyone else is thinking I need today's date in python which I already have in my script. I wish people would just read my question.  Thank you for trying!!!

Comment: @JatonJameerJustice the reason of error is unicodeescape. You should use 2 times '\' that symbol on path folder. 
Try to update your Monday like that
Monday = """\\VGMSTATION\\Users\\VGMPC2\\Documents\\Vlcscheduler\\Playlist\\Platformer"""

Comment: I tried that and no luck. I also tried something easier that I know works: `C:/windows/notepad.exe` and that failed too. I know that works because I can just open python byitself and run `subprocess.call(notepad)` with the variable `notepad="""C:/windows/notepad.exe"""'

Comment: Hmm that's bad. I am sorry that I could not help you anymore. I hope you will find your answer. Good luck!

Comment: Hey @Orhan Solak I was able to get it to work using the method you gave. I just was being stupid and didn't put the variables above `now = datetime.datetime.now()`. I also had to add an `r` to my string variables so that the path would work properly. I apologize as I had to go to work and I kinda asked this question in a rush because it was on my mind. I thank you for helping me out here.

Comment: Welcome ! No worries, as long as it works, I am happy for you. Good luck on next projects !

Answer (score 1):

Below your days maybe something like:
If you call datetime.datetime.now(), there should be a method called weekday() which returns the integer value of the current day of the week. (0-6)

```
dict = {0: Sunday, 1: Monday, 2: Tuesday, 3: Wednesday, 4: Thursday, 5: Friday, 6: Sunday}

>>> datetime.datetime.now().weekday()
0

subprocess.call(dict[datetime.datetime.now().weekday()])
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I already have the code to get the weekday. `now = datetime.datetime.now()
tdate = (now.strftime("%A"))
print(tdate)`

I need to know how to use my variables to run the path.